# Is there a downside to always returning Access-Control-Allow-Credentials?

Tags: security, cors, http-headers

A weird CORS question...

I have code in my *example.co*m server which returns the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header for all POST & GET requests where the Origin request header is passed and it has a value of an example.com sub-domain (*superman.example.com*, *batman.example.com*, etc.).

I now need to be able to make AJAX calls passing cookies, so I need to be able to return the **Access-Control-Allow-Credentials** response header if the request includes cookies.

I could add an additional check to return the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials response header if I see the Cookie request header, but for simplicity, I'm wondering if there is any downside to **always** returning the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials response header for all GET/POST requests from my sub-domains, where the Origin request header is specified.

Here's my code (it's a Tcl iRule, FWIW):

```
when HTTP_REQUEST priority 200 {
    if { ( [HTTP::method] equals "OPTIONS" ) and
         ( [HTTP::host] ends_with "example.com"] ) and
         ( [HTTP::header exists "Access-Control-Request-Method"]) } {
        HTTP::respond 200 "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" [HTTP::header "Origin"] \
                          "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "POST, GET, OPTIONS" \
                          "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" [HTTP::header "Access-Control-Request-Headers"] \
                          "Access-Control-Max-Age" "86400"       
    } elseif { ( [HTTP::host] ends_with "example.com"] ) and
               ( [HTTP::header exists "Origin"]) } {
        # CORS GET/POST requests - set cors_origin variable
        set cors_origin [HTTP::header "Origin"]
    }
}
when HTTP_RESPONSE {
    # CORS GET/POST response - check cors_origin variable set in request
    if { [info exists cors_origin] } {
        HTTP::header insert "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" $cors_origin
        HTTP::header insert "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" "true"
    }
}
```

I am aware that if I return the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials response header, I have to specify a named (non-generic) Access-Control-Allow-Origin header (and *that* may have Vary header issues), but is there anything else I need to be aware of?

Comment: No-one answered this question, even after I added a bounty:( I am ASSUMING that there is no downside, but if anyone in the future reads this question and knows differently, please add a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take [defence in depth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defense_in_depth_(computing)) into consideration, unconditionally including

```http
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

in responses is a bad idea. Your app may indeed be vulnerable to [HTTP-header injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_header_injection). Imagine a situation where the attacker is able to inject—perhaps via a query parameter in the URL—exactly one arbitrary HTTP header in the response. In that case, the attacker would effectively be able to force responses to contain the following headers,

```http
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://attacker.com
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

which would leave the content wide open to cross-origin attacks from `https://attacker.com`.

[James Kettle](https://twitter.com/albinowax) [mentions something similar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=22CKQ_xed9s&t=35m40s) in his AppSecUSA 2016 talk, entitled *Exploiting CORS Misconfigurations for Bitcoins and Bounties*:

> It's quite common to find classic HTTP-header-injection vulnerabilities where, for whatever reason, you can't inject into the response content. You can't just inject malicious HTML; the only thing you can do is set HTTP
> headers. And CORS offers a brilliant way of exploiting this because you can just say
>
> > This content is open to everyone!
>
> using CORS and then attackers can get hold of that [...]

Comment: It's a reasonable answer (to a 6-year-old question :). But as you say, it's only really an issue if the attacker is able to inject HTTP response headers (specifically an ACAO response header) which is very application-dependent. Although unless they are also able to remove the existing ACAO response header, then there will be two ACAO response headers returned to the browser, which will cause most browsers to throw an error. Plus, of course, the original request may not work, since `https://attacker.com` does not match the Origin request header... But your point is well-taken.